# Установка кодировки в UTF-8 для текущего соединениния с MySQL

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Добрый день.

Результат sql-запроса возвращается не в `UTF-8` кодировке. Пытался установить кодировку с помощью функции `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db)`, но по все видимости функция не работает, при том, что MySQL версии 5.0.7. Как можно по другому задать кодировку соединения, но не используя `SET NAMES`?

З.Ы. Когда работал с той же таблицей при помощи `PDO`, при установке кодировки:

```
$db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')
```

Поля возвращались в `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Самый 100%ый код для 100%ого UTF-8 :D

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

Comment: и совсем без SET NAMES :D

Comment: Вариант с SET NAMES я знаю: mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $db), а вот без него ХЗ!

Ну раз по другому не как, пусть будет ответом... Спасибо.

Comment: А как сделать так же, но только не для `UTF-8`, а для `windows-1251`?

Comment: замени **utf8** на **cp1251**

Answer (score 9):

1. Оригинальное API MySQL (функции `mysql_`) устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0.
2. Для улучшенного модуля MySQL (MySQL Improved) предпочтительным способом является использование метода [set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php).

   ```
   ...
   $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
   ...
   ```

   или

   ```
   ...
   mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
   ...
   ```

   Использование для этих целей метода [query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) (например: `SET NAMES 'utf8'`) **не рекомендуется**.
3. В PDO следует указывать кодировку соединения в параметре `dsn` при создании экземпляра класса работы с бд:

   ```
   ...
   $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=DB;host=HOST;charset=utf8';
   $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
   ...
   ```

P.S. Для работы с четырехбайтовым UTF-8 (например, чтобы эмодзи сохранялись в базу) вместо кодировки `utf8` следует использовать кодировку `utf8mb4`. База также должна быть настроена с использованием utf8mb4.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2):

```
SET NAMES 'utf-8'
```

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема с несрабатываением функции mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8") на локальном веб-сервере denwer - то это связано с тем, что в параметрах denwer по умолчанию назначена кодировка cp1251 - сутки голову ломал.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci');
```