# Неверная кодировка на сайте

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Скажите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так. На сайте вместо русских букв кракозябры, а там где значения вставляются из БД знаки вопроса. Уже все перепробовал, результат тот же. На Денвере все работало нормально. На хостинге стоит кодировка `Windows-1251`, `*.php`-файлы в кодировке `ANSI`, на `СУБД` стоит `collation cp1251_general_ci`.

Comment: Вам сюда: [Кодировка mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/установка-кодировки-в-utf-8-для-текущего-соединениния-с-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите кодировку самой БД. Если все ок - кодировку таблиц, если и там все ок - кодировку полей таблиц. Чудес не бывает...

Answer (score 0):

попробуй это после подключения к бд

```
mysql_query('set character_set_client="Вашаа кодировка"');
    mysql_query('set character_set_results="сюда тоже вашу кодировку"');
```

и сахраните файлы в кодировке windows1251

Comment: ко всему совет пользоваться UTF8

Answer (score 0):

После подключения бд:

```
mysql_query('set charset utf8');
mysql_query('set names utf8');
mysql_query('set character_set_client="utf8"');
mysql_query('set character_set_connection="utf8"');
mysql_query('set character_set_result="utf8"');
```