# php форма не отправляет кирилицу в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

задача проста — заполнить форму и отправить все в базу данных mysql. Но почему то к базе данных доходит только английские слова, русские не доходят.

С базой данный все норм, если напрямую через phpmyadmin туда загрузить текст то все норм. А если самому вводить в форму, то как будто переменная `$_POST` не принимает кирилицу, и запись в базе данных пустая

Как это изменить?

Comment: Код хотя бы покажи для начала.

Comment: В поиске бы ввели тут `mysql utf`, много интересного бы нашли. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-utf-8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-mysql

Comment: @Mike: а чего не отмечаете дубликатом?

Comment: @NickVolynkin потому что автор так ничего и не ответил, есть же вероятность, что проблема не в кодировке.

Comment: @Mike: эх, ну если ответит и нужно будет снять дубликат — сообщите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста, помогло ли вам решение из ответа [Установка кодировки в UTF-8 для текущего соединениния с MySQL](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/37043)?

Answer (score 1):

После подключения к базе напиши

```
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php