# Перобразовать данные в базе данных в другую кодировку

Tags: mysql, sql, кодировка, перекодировка

Доброго времени! Есть такая проблема - есть сайт ([Ссылка](http://corepro.kz/goods.php)) с базой данных в ней записано очень много данных. С самого начала была ошибка и кирилица в базу записывалась так

```
ÐšÐ¾Ð½Ñ†ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ñ‚ ÑÑ‹Ð²Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ‡Ð½Ð¾Ð³Ð¾ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ñ‚ÐµÐ¸Ð½Ð°
```

Но это вид в Pma на самом сайте все отображалось корректно. Но сегодня что то на хостинге сделали что теперь и на сайте стало так же.
Есть ли способ как то керекодировать данные в самой БД что бы перевести эти иероглифы в кирилицу - кодировка страниц сайта

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Кодировка таблиц и БД   utf8_general_ci тип таблиц InnoDB

Как можно перекодировать данные в БД в корректный вид?

Дополняю: судя по картинке [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/) этои иероглифы пошли по тому что данные были в utf-8 и база в utf-8 а соединение было в cp1252

Comment: речь о MySql как я понимаю? добавьте тэг

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Установка кодировки в UTF-8 для текущего соединениния с MySQL](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-utf-8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-mysql)

Comment: @4per да верно mysql сайту 2 года до сегодняшнего для все работало нормально

Comment: @androschuk нет к сожалению те вответы не работаю - добавление к соединению 3х строк $db = mysql_connect ("*******","******","*****");
$dd = mysql_select_db ("*******",$db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'"); ничего не меняют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разрешил задачу - размещу тут развернутое решение может кому то еще пригодится, дело было в том что данные записывались в дефолтной кодировке соединения с сервером а именно mysql_query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");

в итоге просто экспортировал на локальный хост базу данных с хоста, и создал ее дубликат с полностью очищенными (пустыми таблицами) и запустил вот такой скрипт

```
define('BD_HOST','localhost'); //хост бд
define('BD_PASS','password'); //пароль бд
define('BD_LOGIN','dante');  //Логин бд
define('BD_FROM','coa');   //исходная БД
 define('BD_IN','coreprot');   //конечная БД

$tables = array (   'bask',
'bonus',
'razdel',
'tovar'); //Массив со всеми таблицами которые надо переписать нормально

foreach ($tables as $table) {
mysql_connect(BD_HOST,BD_LOGIN,BD_PASS);
mysql_select_db(BD_FROM);
mysql_query("set names 'latin1'");//тут ставим дефолтную корявую кодировку (Это важно!!!)

$query_select_from = "SELECT * FROM $table;";
$result = mysql_query($query_select_from);

mysql_close();   //запросили все косячные данные и закрыли соединение

mysql_connect(BD_HOST,BD_LOGIN,BD_PASS);
mysql_select_db(BD_IN);
mysql_query("set names utf8");   //открыли новое соединение, но уже указав нормальную кодировку


while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $values = '';
    $f = false;
    foreach($t as $val) {
        $p = ($f)?',':'';
        $f = true;
        $add = (is_int($val))?"$val":"'$val'";
        $values.= "$p $add";
    };
    $insert_in = "INSERT $table VALUES($values)";
    mysql_query($insert_in);   //запись прочтенной строки, уже в нормальном соединении
};
mysql_close();   //закрываем соединение, что бы открыть его уже для другой таблицы.
```

};

в итоге база данных перезаписалась в нормальной кодировке и в pma и на сайте все отлично, сразу выставил при соединении нормальную кодировку так:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

и все профит, ГЛАВНОЕ повторяю тут угадать начальную кодировку соединения в которой все было записано по косячному

Answer (score 0):

Как на счет:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/37059/2110)

Comment: К сожалению пробовал не меняет, тут пока единственный вариант который мне видится - это просто перекодировать все данные в БД с одной каодировки в другую но я плохо представляю как это лучше сделать вот и прошу помощи\