# Создание БД в denwer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, denwer

Помогите я использую denwer при создании базы в phpmyadmin я везде указываю сравнение utf8_general_ci.Эта же кодировка стоит в разделе

> Сопоставление кодировки соединения с MySQL

. Но при попытке из страницы добавить строку выписывает Âëàä

Код страницы в которой ввожу данные:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

`// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 

// экранирования символов для mysql
$name = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']));
$company = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['company']));

// создание строки запроса
$query ="INSERT INTO phones VALUES(NULL, '$name','$company')";

// выполняем запрос
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
if($result)
{
    echo "<span style='color:blue;'>Данные добавлены</span>";
}
// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link);`


}
?>

### Добавить новую модель

Введите модель:

Производитель:

Comment: Кодировка самих файлов с php-скриптами тоже utf-8?

Comment: Возможно на ваш вопрос уже ответили [Установка кодировки в UTF-8 для текущего соединениния с MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-utf-8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-mysql)

Comment: @moxon кодировка файлов скриптов utf-8 witout BOM.

Comment: @AlexeyRyabov должно помочь но я не понимаю куда вписать эти строки: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

Comment: я попытался пере сохранить скрипты в кодировке cp1251 + создал новые БД и подключил их к файлу но теперь он вообще не вводит текст в кортежи. Создаются новые кортежи но поля пустые все кроме ключевого