# Проблемы с кодировкой UTF-8

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, что при выгрузке данных из базы и конвертации их в json получаю ошибку `"Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"`. Решил её следующей функцией:

```
public static function convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($data)
{
    if (is_string($data))
        return utf8_encode($data);
    if (!is_array($data))
        return $data;
    $patched_data = array();
    foreach ($data as $index => $value)
        $patched_data[$index] = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($value);
    return $patched_data;
}
```

Но столкнулся со следующей проблемой, при показе данных они выглядят следующим образом:

[image: Текст в кодировке UTF-8]

На странице выставлено: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Структура таблицы следующая:

[image: Структура таблицы]

Некоторые записи из базы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не совсем понимаю, что не так, у меня есть подозрение, что данные, которые добавляются в базу, добавляются не в той кодировке. Данные добавляются пользователями, вручную.

Добавление происходит через эту функцию:

```
public static function create($project, $title, $type)
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$connection) {
        return false;
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO reports(creation_date, project, title, creator, type, status, link) VALUES ("
        . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 'now()') . ", "
        . "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $project) . "'" . ", "
        . "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $title) . "'" . ", "
        . "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, Auth::get_user_id()) . "'" . ", "
        . "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $type) . "'" . ", "
        . "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 'preparation') . "'" . ", "
        . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 'NULL')
        . ")";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ? mysqli_insert_id($connection) : false;
    mysqli_close($connection);
    return $result;
}
```

Забираются данные через эту функцию:

```
public static function get()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$connection) {
        return json_encode(array());
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM reports";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_close($connection);
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

От себя хочу добавить, что в PHP я новичок и для меня это не слишком тривиальная задача. Если будут замечания по коду - пишите, выслушаю ваши предложения.

**Обновление #1**

После выставления кодировки соединению, с помощью `$connection->set_charset('utf8');`, проблема с json `"Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"` была устранена и была удалена функция `convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively` так как стала ненужной.
Но символы на странице остались в таком же формате.

Comment: Кодировку соединения нужно устанавливать после подключения к базе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726863/186083

Comment: @Visman спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Visman да, это помогло избавиться от проблемы "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" и привело к удалению ненужной функции convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively. Но символы на странице остались прежними

Comment: а вы записи создали заново ? боюсь они у вас сейчас в БД лежат дважды кодированные в utf-8...

Comment: @Mike сейчас попробую добавить новую запись с новыми рельсами

Comment: главное при добавлении то же не забыть кодировку указать у сессии

Comment: @Mike да, я уже добавил новый класс, для открытия соединения и закрытия и в нём 2 функции сделал (open и close), в open как раз все выставляется, всё через этот класс теперь ходит

Comment: @Mike да, всё отлично с новой записью, сейчас подредактирую старые. Спасибо вам большое! :-)