# Mysql обрезает текст со смайлами

Tags: php, mysql

Получаю текст, он содержит смайлики эмодзи, пример:
https://emojio.ru/animals-nature/d83cdf44-1f344-grib.html
сохраняю эту строку в mysql средствами php.
текст обрезается ровно до 1-го смайла. Тоесть до смайла текст есть, смайл пропадает и дальше текста тоже нет, хотя текста там еще огого.
Может как то надо строку преобразовать? у меня стоит в mysql utf8-general-ci
может что-то другие надо?

Comment: И на этот ответ посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726863/186083

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужно использовать другую кодировку. Поставьте utf8mb4_general_ci, вместо utf8 general ci

Comment: да поставил. теперь сохраняет. но при  выводе на странице - вместо этих смайликов - ???? по 4 знака вопроса