# Вопросительные знаки ИЗ mysql

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Дорогие друзья , информация в базу заносится нормально. Таблица БД под кодировкой UTF8. Там т е в таблице mysql русские буквы отображаются нормально. А вот на странице (когда извлекаю информацию из базы данных) вопросительные знаки вместо русских букв . что делать уже 4 часа голову ломаю (

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726863/186083

Comment: дык указывал после соединения mysqli_query($con1,"SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysqli_query($con1,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con1,"SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

Comment: mysqli_set_charset($con1, "utf8") ; тоже не помогает

Comment: Так у вас может браузер определяет страницу не как UTF-8? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` на странице прописан?

Comment: прописан header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: и сохранил UTF-8 БЕЗ BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_db');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8mb4");
```

Answer (score -2):

Перепробовал кучу вариантов, в том числе с перекодировкой базы, дампы и тд и ничего не помогло. Только вот это вариант выше действительно помог. Делайте именно как написано. В phpMyAdmin -> Основные настройки -> Сопоставление кодировки соединения и там выставляем  кодировку "cp1251_general_ci". И уже в вашем php после коннекта с БД

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Я создавал базу в MySQL Workbench. Может после этого пошли какие-то глюки кодировки. Хотя в самом SQL везде указано UTF8.

Comment: Вырезал новый вопрос. Думаю, вам стоит его задать отдельно, дав ссылку на текущий.