# Не работает запрос с русскими буквами в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

У меня есть Ajax запрос на странице . Очень простой

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#textbox2').bind("change past keyup", function(){

            var lenght = $('#textbox2').val().length;
            if(lenght >= 3) 
            {
                var val = $('#textbox2').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/auth/search',
                    data: {searchstring: val},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('.results').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Вот код файла PHP к которому идёт запрос:

```
    $search = $_POST['searchstring'];
    $res = Bamd::search($search);
```

И вот код метода search($search) объекта Bamd

```
$db2 = DB::getConnection2();
$proc = '%';
$string .= $proc; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stations WHERE index_en LIKE '".(string)$string."' OR index_ru LIKE '".(string)$string."' AND country_en='Russia'";

$query = $db2->query($sql);
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = $query->fetchAll();
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
exit();
```

Вот так выглядит таблица stations:

```
id | index_ru | index_en | country_en
1  | УЕБД     | UEBD     | Russia
2  | УЕБС     | UEBS     | Russia
3  | УЕБТ     | UEBT     | Russia
...
```

Если я ввожу в строку латинские символы например UEB, все работает абсолютно корректно, var_dump`ятся правильные строки из бд.

Но если я пишу по-русски , например УЕБ , то var_dump`ится пустой массив

```
array(0) {
}
```

Почему??? В чем причина? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: кодировка БД utf-8

Comment: "кодировка БД utf-8" - а точнее?

Comment: и кодировка соединения установлена? (скорее всего нет)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как её установить?

Comment: @Dmitriy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/37059/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот эта строка? mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

Comment: @Dmitriy обычно `SET NAMES/SET CHARACTER SET` должно хватать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `utf8_general_ci`? Может `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня квакозябры не появятся в БД?)

Comment: @Dmitriy ну вы тестовыми данными на локальном компе побалуйтесь и посмотрите) или вы на боевом сразу? :)

Comment: @Dmitriy сделайте бэкап да проверьте. А вообще прежде, чем следовать советам шестилетней давности, добавьте информацию о таблице и БД к вопросу.

Comment: @svgrafov зависит от версии MySQL на самом деле

Comment: @Dmitriy для PDO кстати, вполне себе ответ 2017 года - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726863/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , запустил SET NAMES/SET CHARACTER SET, тоже самое, utf-8 и стояла кажется

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Mysql 5.5.3 с mb4 вышла 7 лет назад. Пора уже закопать cтюардессу(<5.5.3).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ахахах

Comment: @svgrafov это не мне надо говорить....я самолично никого не бегаю и не принуждаю под дулом пистолета на чем-то работать :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот это помогло $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']};"; добавил сюда charset=utf8, все заработало! Спасибо